# Have we really measured the wavelength of light?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wavelength

Have we practically measured the distances between the variations of electromagnetic radiations in space in nanometers or is it just theoritical because of calculations?

Also the one who have marked duplicate i didn't understand the answer so please anyone who can answer please explain in simple language as well as less mathematical notions.

Comment: The key concept here is wavelength interferometer. Look up the Michelson interferometer. You can replicate this measurement in a home lab for a few hundred dollars with a differential micrometer, a cube beamspliter, some mirrors, a small laser, a microscope objective and quite a bit of time on your hands....

Comment: @JohnRennie and other 2 i have edited my question

Comment: I ask an other question about the used parameters for the calculation of wavelength [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177841/physical-reality-of-calculated-wavelength-from-two-measurable-phenomena-slit-dis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a process called interference, we can find wavelength, because the way that waves interfere is reliant of wavelength. Interference is based off of two key principles of waves: they are made up of peaks and troughs. When troughs overlap, they go lower. When peaks overlap, thy go higher. When a peak meets a trough, they cancel. Of course, the positions of waves and troughs is dependent on wavelength, therefore, one can calculate the wavelength by looking at the interference pattern. As you can see in the picture, using two waves, we can find wavelength.[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you explain better and edit your answer? But i will not give you a -1 but if a edit your answer and explain better i will definitely give you a +1.

Comment: @Bhavesh edited